# "Going down the rathole" vs. "Going down the rabbit hole."

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, expression-choice

I hear/read the phrase "going down a/the rathole" used as a synonym for the phrase "going down a/the rabbit hole," the later taken from chapter 1 - "Down the Rabbit Hole" of *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*, by Lewis Carroll.

For example, "let's not go down a rat hole," "that topic is a rathole," etc.  I've often encountered this in meetings where a topic or past event is brought up and is then responded to with "let's not go down that rat hole," or a similar variation used to state that a topic, or issue is so confusing, complex, or outside of reality and reason that it would be impossible or at least not beneficial to discuss.  There could a time component, but the main point is being unable to reason about something.

Google's definition of **rathole** is

> noun: rathole; plural noun: ratholes; noun: rat-hole; plural noun:
> rat-holes
>
> 1. informal a cramped or squalid room or building.
> 2. NORTH AMERICAN informal used to refer to the waste of money or resources. "pouring our assets down the rathole of military
>    expenditure"

One of [Wikipedia's explanations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_hole) of **rabbit hole** is

> "down the rabbit hole", a metaphor for an entry into the unknown, the
> disorientating or the mentally deranging, from its use in Alice's
> Adventures in Wonderland a slang expression for a psychedelic
> experience, from the same usage.

I cringe when I hear *rathole* used instead of *rabbit hole*, because of two issues:

1. What exactly is a rat hole (is this really a widely known fact or idea)?
2. The deeper idea (e.g. magnitude of the confusion) trying to be conveyed seems to be lost with *rathole* because the reference to *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* is at worst lost, or at best greatly degraded. Consider *vanity* versus *[narcissism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism)* -- the later having a mythological aspect which communicates a larger idea in a single word.

My question is this, are both usages correct/synonymous to state that discussing an issue or past experience would be so disorienting, complex, or confusing, so as to not be beneficial?

Comment: "Rat hole" and "rabbit hole" are two different terms with different meanings.  The uses you quote (absent any significant context) sound to be more appropriate for "rat hole" than "rabbit hole".  What makes you think the uses are not correct?

Comment: The usages I am referring to relate to interacting with information or ideas, e.g. someone brings up a topic and the response is, "let's not go down that rathole."  From the explanations of both words above, the phrase "rabbit hole" seems more appropriate.

Comment: If a topic is known to be a time-waster, eg, it's validly referred to as a "rat hole".

Comment: "Waste of money or resources" -- a "rat hole" is a "bottomless pit".

Comment: Note that the primary feature of "rabbit hole" is disorientation -- when you go down the rabbit hole you lose grip on "reality".

Comment: "The deeper idea trying to be conveyed seems to be lost with rathole" - What deeper idea? You haven't given us any context or mentioned any deep ideas.  How can we say it has been lost if we don't know what is being described?

Comment: What's wrong with "down the rathole"? (Though "down **A** rathole" would be a bit more idiomatic, and is actually what your examples quote.)

Comment: None of the examples you give (“Let's not go down that rathole” or “That topic is a rathole” in the context of a discussion in a meeting) would work with _rabbit hole_. That would simply make them nonsensical, barring some kind of tenuous context that is definitely not present in the examples as given. As others have said, both usages are correct, but not synonymous. You're the one mixing them up and misusing (one of) them, not the ones using ‘down a rathole’.

Comment: I've been in plenty of meetings where we *did* fall into a rat hole.  There was never anything "confusing" -- simply the fact that certain people clung desperately to conflicting opinions such that we could talk until we were blue in the face and never get anywhere.  Actual rabbit holes are quite rare compared to the frequency of rat holes.

Comment: "Down a rabbit hole" would be if someone came in and wanted to discuss something like quantum computing, when no one had the background to understand it.

Comment: Rat-holes in your kitchen mean you're either throwing everything out or you're getting the plague.  From WW1 trench warfare straight on through to the pit traps and jungle tunnels of Vietnam, US armed forces (the example in the OP was military and rabbit holes are not FUBAR,  compare rat hole) went underground a lot; and experienced a lot of casualties therein. Rats. Rats and rat holes are a commonly understood idea in the world.  Maybe your coworkers are mixing them up, but there is some overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both their origins and their current usage suggest different meaning. I think that they are just  sometime misused involuntarily:

***[Rat-hole](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=rathole%20&searchmode=none):***

> - also rathole, 1812 in figurative sense of "nasty, messy place;" rat (n.) + hole (n.). As "bottomless hole" (especially one where money goes) from 1961.

(Etymonline)

***[Rabbit hole](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rabbit%20hole)***:

> - a bizarre or difficult state or situation —usually used in the phrase *down the rabbit hole.*

(origin)

> - from the rabbit hole that Alice enters in Lewis Carroll's Alice in Wonderland
>     First Known Use: 1980

(M-W)

Comment: Please see the edits to my question. I am comparing "down the rathole" and "down the rabbit hole" rather than rathole and "down the rabbit hole."

Comment: No one has yet demonstrated that people commonly confuse these two.  The confusion appears to be on the part of those saying "down a rat hole" is not appropriate.  And they are ***not*** synonymous.

Comment: What misuse?  No one had demonstrated any misuse yet!!!

Comment: **What are the examples of "misuse" that are being discussed here??**

Comment: I don't get them confused.

Comment: @Josh61 No, no, you're supposed to reply, "Easy for *you* to say."

Comment: There are less than a dozen instances of *not go down a/the rat hole/rathole* in Google Books, but they all refer to the prospect of (usually, *public*) money going ***down the drain*** (into the sewers, where rats live).

Answer (score 2):

Down the rabbit-hole implies going into the unknown, as rabbits tend to disappear quickly.

In a rat-hole describes being in a closed up filthy environment.

See also Spider-Hole. for a scary combination of the two.

Comment: I don't think that "down the rabbit-hole" implies going into the unknown, do you have evidence to support it.

Comment: @Josh61 - Have you ever read *Alice in Wonderland*?

Comment: @Josh61: Also note the reasonably common usage [lost in a warren](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lost+in+a+warren%22) - a literal or figurative labyrinthine network, where the way through is usually unknown/confusing.