# Looking for a word - thing that wastes a lot of time

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for a words for a thing in which you invest a lot of time but don't gain anything. For example using whatsapp.

Comment: I would say stackexchange.com.

Comment: [English equivalent for the Persian idiom “send someone out in pursuit of black chickpeas”](//english.stackexchange.com/q/337067/26083) lists “wild goose chase,” “snipe hunt,” “fool’s errand,” and others.

Comment: Another similar question: [What is a witty synonym for the phrase “waste of time?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256856)

Comment: @sumelic ~ Even Hot Licks's comment is a duplicate. What a strange phenomenon.

Answer (score 3):

Timesink is a word that is going to convey both the investment of time as well as the futility.

It is usually used in the case of, for example, a video game, and would work in your situation as well.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are duplicates, and that clearly already show that answer

Answer (score 0):

[**Distraction**](https://www.google.com/search?q=distraction%20definition) **-** a thing that prevents someone from giving full attention to something else.

[**Vain**](https://www.google.com/#q=define+vain) **-** producing no result; useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try "[boondoggle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/boondoggle)."  A "boondoggle" is an unnecessary or wasteful project.

You might also try "[black hole](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/black--hole?s=t)."  When used figuratively, a black hole is something that you can invest endless resources into--time, money, whatever--and they will completely disappear without any kind of pay off or coming to any kind of gain.

Answer (score 0):

In a work environment, say if you were investigating a issues, you could lose a lot of time **going down a rat hole** or **rabbit hole**

See this old question :

["Going down the rathole" vs. "Going down the rabbit hole."](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/281429/131620)